# fixing my table using MySQL with null values

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.

Here's my sample data:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jYQJPV1X1XPbLp72LqA5CZ/1

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.A, 0) AS CODE,
    CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(t2.DESCRIPTION, 'NOT VALID') ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS SEX,
    t1.TOTAL,
    ROUND(100.0 * t1.TOTAL / SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (), 2) AS PERCENT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY t1.A) AS CUMULATIVE,
    ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY t1.A) /
                  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.A IS NOT NULL THEN t1.TOTAL ELSE 0 END) OVER (), 2) AS CUMPERCENT
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A,
        COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM AA
    GROUP BY A WITH ROLLUP
) t1
LEFT JOIN BB t2
    ON t2.CODE = t1.A
ORDER BY
    CODE;
```

Output:

```
CODE | SEX       | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL       1       16.67     0            0.00
0      TOTAL       7       116.67    0            0.00
1      Male        3       50.00     3            50.00
2      Female      2       33.33     5            83.33
3      NOT VALID   1       16.67     6            100.00
```

Expected Output:

```
CODE | SEX       | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL       7       100.00    0            0.00
1      Male        3       42.86     3            42.86
2      Female      2       28.57     5            71.43
3      NOT VALID   1       14.29     6            85.71
4      BLANK       1       14.29     7            100.00
```

I just want to make the table with NULL sex be included and rename it to 'BLANK'. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What would be your expected result if there where more rows in AA that do not match in BB, like 4 and 5?

Comment: @forpas That was a very informative question and thank you for that. If that will be the case, another row will be added with another description. But as of now, I would like first to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: A question. Do you REALLY need NULL in `CODE` column to be replaced with definite value (`4` in shown case)? Do you need this column in output at all?

Comment: For me, I am using it to sort my output table. I want the output table to be sorted that way so I recode it. If there's another way, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution for this sample data, as you say in your comment, then this will work:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT MAX(CASE 
               WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 4
               WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 3
               ELSE a.A
             END  
         ) CODE,
         CASE 
           WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 'BLANK' 
           WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 'NOT VALID'
           ELSE b.description 
         END SEX,
         COUNT(*) TOTAL,
         ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) PERCENT
  FROM AA a LEFT JOIN BB b ON b.code = a.A
  GROUP BY SEX
)
SELECT CODE, SEX, TOTAL, PERCENT, 
       SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) CUMULATIVE, 
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) CUMPERCENT
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), 100.00, 0, 0.00
FROM AA
ORDER BY CODE
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1b3574346a5ed390d3af26b96b12993).
Results:

```
> CODE | SEX       | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
> ---: | :-------- | ----: | ------: | ---------: | ---------:
>    0 | TOTAL     |     7 |  100.00 |          0 |       0.00
>    1 | Male      |     3 |   42.86 |          3 |      42.86
>    2 | Female    |     2 |   28.57 |          5 |      71.43
>    3 | NOT VALID |     1 |   14.29 |          6 |      85.71
>    4 | BLANK     |     1 |   14.29 |          7 |     100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT AA.A AS code,
                 CASE WHEN AA.A IS NULL
                      THEN 'BLANK'
                      WHEN BB.description IS NULL
                      THEN 'NOT VALID'
                      ELSE BB.description
                      END description,
                 COUNT(*) AS amount
          FROM AA
          LEFT JOIN BB ON AA.A = BB.code
          GROUP BY AA.A, BB.description ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT SUM(amount) amount, MAX(code) + 1 code
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT 0 code, 
       'TOTAL' description, 
       amount,
       100 percent,
       0 cumulative,
       0 cumulative_percent
FROM cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(cte1.code, cte2.code) code, 
       cte1.description, 
       cte1.amount,
       100 * cte1.amount / cte2.amount,
       SUM(cte1.amount) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(cte1.code, cte2.code)),
       100 * SUM(cte1.amount) OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(cte1.code, cte2.code)) / cte2.amount
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83f0679be735eee00baf77724688eb05)

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I rename the 'BLANK' into 'TOTAL'? This is at Row1 Column 'sex'..

Comment: @CarloKarganilla I rewrite the query - it's easier to use UNION at the end then to take into account that we have 3 different NULLs over the whole query. The query is safe/stable to a lot of non-existent codes in AA (except the case when its value is MAX for its datatype). For to understand execute `cte1` as separate query.